# OnStop() OnPause OnDestroy() not called

Tags: android, android-activity, timer, android-asynctask, timertask

I created a chat application in android
and for refreshing and getting new messages from otherside person, i used a `TimerTask` which runs a asynctask each 10 second... My problem is when i close this activity, timer task wont destroy and stop! even i put the code `Timertask.cancel()` in onStop() onPause and onDestroy() i put even some Log to see this methods work or not... but i realize that nothing of them called and timertask running for ever... even when i close the app!!!

My question is, when i use this *TimerTask* and *AsyncTask* which i mentioned it, why those methods such as *onStop()*, *onPause()* and *onDestroy()* are never called???

What should i do for solve this problem. Any other suggestion...?

thanks in advance...

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: just a wild guess, your chat activity starts timertask and keeps some sort of refference on the activity?